# Conditional value in helper method in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to set a parameter in this helper method, but I'm not sure if is possible to use a ternary operator or something to set a value with some condition.

```
<%= number_field_tag 'somearray[][somefield]', nil, {min: 0.000, step: 0.001, class: "form-control", :'aria-label' => "Quantity" ,onchange: "change_total(this)",value: 'VALUE SHOULD BE HERE'} %>
```

The condition is something like this:

```
if params['somearray'].nil? != true
   return params['somearray'].first["quantity"]
else
   return nil
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of [`number_field_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag) is actually the value, so you can certainly set it there with a ternary operator (which I've simplified based on the fact that `nil` is falsy):

```
number_field_tag 'somearray[][somefield]', (params[:somearray] ? params[:somearray][0][:quantity] : nil), min: 0.000, step: 0.001, class: "form-control", :'aria-label' => "Quantity", onchange: "change_total(this)"
```

However, complex in-line view operations are best refactored to a helper file. Helper files are defined in the app/helpers directory and named based on the controller: if you have a `PagesController`, you'd want to add the method to `module PagesHelper` in app/helpers/pages_helper.rb (note that the `params` method is still accessible from the helper file even without passing it in):

```
def somearray_value
  params[:somearray] ? params[:somearray][0][:quantity] : nil
end
```

Then you can call it in the view:

```
number_field_tag 'somearray[][somefield]', somearray_value, min: 0.000, step: 0.001, class: "form-control", :'aria-label' => "Quantity", onchange: "change_total(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) for that:

```
<%= number_field_tag 'somearray[][somefield]', params[:somearray].try(:first).try(:fetch, :quantity), {min: 0.000, step: 0.001, class: "form-control", :'aria-label' => "Quantity" ,onchange: "change_total(this)" %>
```